# characteristic function upper bound and uniformly continuous.

Tags: probability-theory, characteristic-functions

Let $X$ be a random variable and let $\phi$ be its characteristic function.
Let $A$ be a nonnegative constant and consider the following inequality
$$
|\phi(t)-\phi(s)| \leq \sqrt{A|1-\phi(t-s)|}.
$$
Show that if the inequality holds for all random variables then $A\geq 2$. Specifically,
show that for any $A< 2$ there is an $X$ for which the inequality fails.

I am not quite sure about how to use the uniform continuity to prove this conclusion.

Comment: Maybe we should apply some techniques in Fourier analysis.

Answer (score 1):

> I am not quite sure about how to use the uniform continuity to prove this conclusion.

Then don't.

> Maybe we should apply some techniques in Fourier analysis.

Hmmm... And maybe we should look for explicit simple counterexamples?

Try $X$ such that $P(X=1)=1$, and $s=0$, $t\to0$.

Comment: Thank you for your attention on this problem. I also came up with such an example and got some idea from this. I once had a thought that we can fix s at 0 since we have uniform continuity and we need just to look up upper bound for the function. Does it make sense?

Comment: Not that I would understand. Did you solve the example in my answer. What did you get?

Comment: I am sorry that I try to find a more general way to solve this problem. This example can show that $A \geq 2$.

Comment: More general ways are allright--but did you manage to apply the specific hints I gave?

Comment: I am sorry. I didn't get your idea.

Comment: There is no idea here, just an example to check. If something mathematical is stopping you in checking this example, please describe it.

Comment: I think this specific example can only tells us that we cannot get A $<$ 2 for all random variables. However, in order to show that $A \geq 2$ for all random variable, we cannot just rely on this specific example.

Comment: Your last comment seems to hint at a deep confusion. Please reread the question.

Comment: Could you please make it clear?

Comment: Make what clear? That you should reread your own question? I already did.